# jQuery one iframe refreshing another iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, refresh, parent

I have jQuery code in two separate scripts loaded in two separate iframes. I need to call one iframe to another. In short, when a change occurs in one iframe, I want the other iframe to change as well, or to call a refresh/reload basically.

Here is the code on my main page:

```
<iframe src="sortImages.php" id="picFrame"></iframe> 
<iframe src="jUpload/index.php"  id="jUploadFrame"></iframe>
```

**What jQuery will allow the iframe called jUploadFrame to refresh the picFrame?**

and the opposite...

**What jQuery code will allow the iframe called picFrame to refresh the jUploadFrame?**

Comment: Don't use iframes; use AJAX. The only good reason to use iframes is to embed content from a different domain.

Comment: ok, how would I do that? One of the reasons I used iFrames was because the css files were conflicting.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will check it out. Hopefully it won't take me too long.

Comment: Blazemonger has a good point.  On top of that, the javascript model severely limits the ability of iframes to be manipulated by the parent page, and probably far less capabilities iframe-to-iframe.  Fix the css, and drop the page content into a DIV using ajax.